# WebClient Does not automatically redirect

Tags: c#, webclient

When logging the login process using Firebug i see that it is like this

```
POST //The normal post request
GET //Automatically made after the login
GET //Automatically made after the login
GET //Automatically made after the login
```

When making a post request using my code below it did not make the automatic GET requests that the browsers is doing.

MY WebClient Handler

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Test
{
    class HttpHandler : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer _mContainer = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _mContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            if (response is HttpWebResponse)
                _mContainer.Add((response as HttpWebResponse).Cookies);
            return response;
        }

        public void ClearCookies()
        {
            _mContainer = new CookieContainer();
        }
    }
}
```

Using Code

```
private static async Task<byte[]> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var postData = new NameValueCollection();
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/", ServerName));

    postData.Add("name", username);
    postData.Add("password", password);

    return await HttpHandler.UploadValuesTaskAsync(uri, postData);
}
```

When trying to track the connection of my application it is only doing the POST Request and not the rest of GET requests. [THAT ARE MADE AUTOMATICALLY IN THE BROWSER]

Comment: Does it fail in the synchronous version as well? With AllowAutoRedirect, I'd expect it to work... possibly it's a problem with redirecting from POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be surprising, given that `HttpWebRequest` is not a browser.  If you need to perform these redirects, then check the [HttpWebResponse.StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx), and make another request if it's a [redirect code in the 300's](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).  Note from the link under 10.3 Redirection 3xx:

> This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request. The action required MAY be carried out by the user agent without interaction with the user if and only if the method used in the second request is GET or HEAD. A client SHOULD detect infinite redirection loops, since such loops generate network traffic for each redirection.

Comment: The webclient does Have AllowAutoRedirect true automatically

Comment: @dbaseman i am asking about WebClient not the derived HttpWebResponse&Request

Comment: @TorlanOther: Well, it doesn't help that nowhere in your sample code do you refer to WebClient at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are wrong, his class is derived from WebCLient.

Comment: @data_smith: True, although I suspect that HttpWebRequest is what's responsible for the redirection...

Answer (score 12):

Try adding

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

right under the

```
var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
```

It solved some similar problems for me, even though `AllowAutoRedirect` is supposed to be `true` by default.