# Download pdf and mp3 from libsyn

Tags: c#, webclient

**The Main Story:**

My sister want to study Korean language from [TalkToMeInKorean](http://www.talktomeinkorean.com/curriculum/) and she request to download `PDF` and `MP3` files on the said website, I thought it's just one audio file and pdf file so I accept her request, so I visit website and then I realize what her want is the whole eBook and AudioBook, so rather than downloading the files manually I decide to make a program to download it automatically.

---

My goal is to download `PDF` or `MP3` file from libsyn but the problem is the permanent link redirecting to a new generated temporary link and become unreachable by `WebClient`.

**For Example:**

If I try to visit the permanet link

> http://media.libsyn.com/talktomeinkorean/ttmik-l1l1.pdf

this link will automatically redirect to temporary link

> http://hwcdn.libsyn.com/p/b/f/b/bfbd671eb80e82bc/ttmik-l1l1.pdf?c_id=1552118&expiration=1441957016&hwt=fcd7f215fc673ee08705ee41e27f016c

and display the PDF or MP3 file.

**Code Snippet:**

```
static string _sourcePdf = "http://media.libsyn.com/talktomeinkorean/ttmik-l{0}l{1}.{2}";

public static void Download(Level level, int lesson, FileType fileType, string path)
{
    if (level == Level.One && lesson > 25)
    {
        return;
    }

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri _uri = new Uri(string.Format(_sourcePdf, (int)level, lesson, fileType));
    string _fileName = string.Format("{0}Level{1}-Lesson{2}.{3}", path, (int)level, lesson, fileType);
    client.DownloadFile(_uri, _fileName);
}
```

So my idea is to navigate first to permanet link and after redirecting to temporary link, I will retrieve the temporary link and set to new URI for downloading. *-"Any idea how to implement this in `WebClient`?"*

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebClient Does not automatically redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039068/webclient-does-not-automatically-redirect)

Comment: @azt are you kidding me? Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such jobs I usually use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). You can generate the command string in C# or any other way, and just let wget do all the dirty work of following redirects or reconnecting,...

Either paste the sequence of the commands in a Command Prompt, or run it through `Process.Start();`

Comment: it's possible to get the redirected uri from Process.Start("browser")?

Comment: No, I mean, install wget, if it is not present on your system. Then simply run a `wget "http://www.whatever.com/file.pdf"` and you have the file downloaded. Most of the time I simply open the html page in a text editor and extract the urls via regex, put the `wget` at the front and paste it in a command prompt, and it downloads all the files. Much faster than writing a program in C#. Except you have a more complicated job with sub-urls you need to parse.

Comment: For Level1 Lesson 1 mp3: `wget -O TTMIK-Lesson-L1L1.mp3 http://media.libsyn.com/media/talktomeinkorean/TTMIK-Lesson-L1L1.mp3`. Works for me. Downloads it to the current directory under the name specified by `-O`

Comment: actually no need for C#: If you are on Windows just use `FOR /L %a IN (1,1,9) DO FOR /L %b IN (1,1,30) DO wget -O TTMIK-Lesson-L%aL%b.mp3 http://media.libsyn.com/media/talktomeinkorean/TTMIK-Lesson-L%aL%b.mp3`. But, please if you really like the resources, consider buying the bulk download they offer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `HttpWebRequest` it by default follows any redirects (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx).