# Webclient is not downloading the image

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am using the C # Webclient to download an image, but there is a problem, because the image is 0 kb.
I don't get an error message during the process.
Can someone help me?
Thank you

```
private static void Download(string _caminhoArquivo, string _nomeArquivo)
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    string _arquivodownl = "C:\\Img\\ImagensMensagens\\" + _nomeArquivo;
                    string url = "https://p2.trrsf.com/image/fget/cf/940/0/images.terra.com/2020/10/16/2020-10-16T140412Z_1_LYNXMPEG9F1AV_RTROPTP_4_BRAZIL-POLITICS.JPG";
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), _arquivodownl);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `DownloadFileAsync`, that's a non-blocking method, that means that it will finish *before* the file has been completelly downloaded.

You have two options:

1-Change the code to be synchronous:

```
 client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), _arquivodownl);
```

In this way the function will finish after downloading the file.

2-Hook to the `DownloadFileCompleted` event:

```
 client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) => { /* Process here the file */ }
 client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), _arquivodownl);
```

This will raise the event `DownloadFileCompleted` *after the file download has been completed*. You can hook the event to a function, I hooked it to a lambda just as an example. Also, you should check `e.Cancelled` and `e.Error` to ensure the download was successful.

This second method has the benefit that will not block your application waiting the download to end.

Also, if you use the second approach you must remove the `using` or you will dispose the `WebClient` before the file has been downloaded.

Comment: Missed [3rd option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328731/12888024) - use `HttpClient` instead of ancient `WebClient` and make the download really `async`.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to assign a user agent in your webclient instance so you don't get blocked or denied a reply by the server you are requesting the image from...

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"

this is the user agent value that worked for my case since some servers don't even reply if they don't find "Edge..." in your user agent param.

See my particular issue here...
[Using WebClient why does the following image link not download? I don't want to use anything other than WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160461/using-webclient-why-does-the-following-image-link-not-download-i-dont-want-to/76160714#76160714)