# Using WebClient why does the following image link not download? I don't want to use anything other than WebClient

Tags: unity-game-engine, webclient

This is the image link that does not download

https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/777955P/3mtm-scotchcaltm-graphic-film-7755se-420-mirror-silver.jpg

Most of any other images download fine. Using the same link above on UnityWebRequest or HttpClient works fine.

Below is my test code using webclient. With the problem link above it just creates a 0 size file and then times out.

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    var name = Path.GetFileName(imageUrl);
    var local = $"C:\\_Temp/" + name;

    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "image/jpeg");
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted(name, local);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(imageUrl), local)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i just got lucky and found the solution myself after trying many header settings. the user agent that got accepted is apparently the one that contains "Edge..."

So for anyone that will have issues downloading images via WebClient please use the following user agent.

**"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"**